# do I use Krb5LoginModule or LdapLoginModule

Tags: java, kerberos, jaas, jgss

Sorry if this is a silly question.
Do I use LdapLoginModule when I want to check if user exist or authorized?
Do I use Krb5LoginMoudle when I want to check if user has a ticket to do work?

Regards,
JemRug

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing they are both forms of logging in , but the underline protocols they are manipulating  is the key. One is talking Kerberos, the other LDAP.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).